# Old version of C syntax differences?

Tags: c

For a very specific project, I need to write a 16-bit program in C and I'm using Microsoft QuickC in MS-DOS to write this program. Now I'm pretty sure the syntax of my program is correct but the program just won't compile and it thinks I have syntax errors. Is this because C-compilers in MS-DOS using an older version of C with different syntax?

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
   printf("Hello World!");
}
```

Not even that simple hello world program will compile and run.

Comment: `main()` might be interpreted as `int main()`, you have to `return` something.

Comment: A whitespace between `#include` and `<stdio.h>` won't hurt.

Comment: @MarounMaroun no, main is the only function in which it is not undefined behavior to not have a return statement - it will always return 0 to the host environment.

Comment: @MarounMaroun also, it's not that it "might" be interpreted as 'int main()', it *must* be interpreted that way, according to the standard, along with variables in certain scopes.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Doesn't it depend on the compiler? That's why I wrote *might*.. I might be wrong :)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII In C99 or above, the exit status is `0` if no return statement isn't explicitly called in `main`. But in C89, the exit status is undefined. I guess this old compiler doesn't support C99.

Comment: @YuHao dude he is compiling with quickc ( its ancient ) .. he doesn't even have stdio.h header  .. forget about it being compatible to -C99

Comment: @sukhvir That's exactly what I meant. I'm trying to say `return 0` is necessary in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should define main as int

so change your code to :

```
  int main() {    // define main as an int returning function

       // your code

       return 0; // Also make sure you have return statement in main
  }
```

and it will compile

Here is what it says in the standards:

1 The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. **It shall be defined with a return type of `int`** :

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

**Edit:**

Ok from your comments .. you are now getting this error:

```
   C1024: cannot open include file 'stdio.h'
```

Here is a cause and solution from microsoft:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/97809

Comment: I'm getting a new error now from the compiler now saying: fatal error C1024: cannot open include file 'stdio.h'

Comment: @Generalkidd are your INCLUDE and LIB environment variables set correctly?

Comment: yep that did the trick. It's strange those variables weren't set up correctly automatically during installation.

Answer (score -1):

You can't omit the type of the function `main`, or any other C function, for that matter.   So, you want

```
void main() { ... }
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) { ... }
```

although with the latter one the compiler will usually require you to return a value.

Comment: Wrong - the type of a function can definitely be ommited, it defaults to `int`, just like variables.

Comment: @sukhvur no, you *can*, but it invokes undefined behavior at run-time.

Comment: You never want `void main(`, `main` **must** return `int`.